# Robots.txt priority question

Tags: php, html, search, robots.txt

If I have these lines in robots.txt:

```
Disallow /folder/
Allow /folder/filename.php
```

Will the filename.php be allowed then?

Which order does google prioritize the lines?

What will happen here for example?:

```
Allow /
Disallow /
```

I am mainly referring to Google here as a search engine.

Thanks

Comment: BTW, Google has a robots.txt generator here: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449

Comment: BTW2: use sitemaps. http://sitemaps.org/protocol.php

Comment: BTW3 these will be ignored unless you add the colon (":") after the directives :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For your first example, yes, the file `/folder/filename.php` will be allowed, as Google will prioritize the most specific rule. See [here](http://tools.seobook.com/robots-txt/) or [check Wikipedia's article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard), for example, for more details.

Furthermore, Google has a detailed documentation on how it uses `robots.txt` over [here](https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_txt).

Edit : For the second example, the `Allow` will be prioritized as per the Wikipedia quote Byron Whitlock posted in his answer.

Comment: +1 and also there is a similar question with an answer at http://www.webmasterworld.com/robots_txt/3090841.htm

Comment: he's right. according to google http://code.google.com/web/controlcrawlindex/docs/robots_txt.html, whichever rule has a longer character length will be followed (regardless of order).

Comment: Agree (at least w.r.t. Google), except for the second one; for the second one, the outcome would be undefined (both paths are equally specific), so you couldn't really count on it going either way for certain (or that search engines would agree). If you see this in your robots.txt file, remove it or make it clearer.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the search engine:

> While by standard implementation the
>   first matching robots.txt pattern
>   always wins, Google's implementation
>   differs in that Allow patterns with
>   equal or more characters in the
>   directive path win over a matching
>   Disallow pattern. Bing uses the
>   Allow or Disallow directive which is
>   the most specific.
>
> In order to be compatible to all
>   robots, if one wants to allow single
>   files inside an otherwise disallowed
>   directory, it is necessary to place
>   the Allow directive(s) first, followed
>   by the Disallow.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard