# Disallow: /*? in robots.txt explanation needed

Tags: html, indexing, seo, robots.txt, google-crawlers

Could someone please tell me if the following rules in my ****robots.txt**** would allow google or **NOT** to crawl the following example links?

**Allow: /search/**

**Disallow: /*?**

it´s an **e-commerce** and I would like to understand if when searching in the **product search bar**, a dynamic link like these would be crawled or not:

https://www.whateverwebsite.de/search/?q=hello

https://www.whateverwebsite.de/category.html?form_new=18658

https://www.whateverwebsite.de/search/?q=grand&productFilter=motive_design%3AGeometric

Those links are generic examples, but I would really like to know if the **Disallow:/*?**
blocks this kind of links to be crawled on not since there is nothing between the **"/"** and the **"?"**.

Thanks a lot in advance and I look forwards to some answers to keep learning :)

Comment: These links will give you a good understanding of robot.txt: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard  &  https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/robots/robots_txt

Comment: Why ask here.  Just test it with Google's [robots.txt testing tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/robots-testing-tool).  It exists to be able to answer questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is answered here: [A Deeper Look At Robots.txt](https://searchengineland.com/a-deeper-look-at-robotstxt-17573)

```
Disallow: /*? # block any URL that includes a ?
```

But, what you also should consider is that conflicting rules are resolved by giving precedence to the longer rule. ([compare here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589431/robots-txt-priority-question))

So, take care that the right rule gets precedence as you want it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use robots.txt testing tool https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/robots-testing-tool?utm_source=support.google.com/webmasters/&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=%206062598
to know what is being blocked or what is not being blocked by search engine.